# Azure refresh token expiration scenario

Tags: azure

Have been reading  on refresh token and could not find  on the following.  information

1. When does an refresh token expire?
2. Can a password change by the main user cause a refresh token to expire?
3. Can I explicitly set some dates for expiration of refresh token

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look of this post.
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/03/20/azure-ad-token-lifetime/

- Refresh tokens last for 14 days, but If you use a refresh token
  within those 14 days, you will receive a new one with a new validity
  window shifted forward of another 14 days. You can repeat this trick
  for up to 90 days of total validity, then you’ll have to
  reauthenticate.
- Refresh tokens can be invalidated at ANY time, for    reasons
  independent from your app (e.g. user changes password). Hence    you
  should NOT take a dependency on the above in your code – your
  logic should always assume that the refresh token can fail at any
  time.
- Refresh tokens issues for guest MSA accounts last only 12 hours